# Can two postgres service share one common PGDATA folder, one at a time

Tags: postgresql

Can I share data between two postgres services in separate machines (PGDATA folder will be in a shared location) while only one service will run at a time?

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL has a number of ways to make sure that you cannot start two postmaster processes on the same data directory, but if you mount a filesystem on two machines, these mechanisms will fail. So you would have to make very sure that you don't start servers on both machines; that would lead to data corruption. Moreover, you'd have to make sure that the remote file system is reliable. A Windows network share isn't, for example.

So, all in all, my only recommendation is "don't do that". For high availability, use a proven shared-nothing architecture like Patroni.

Comment: what about windows failover cluster with postgres?

Comment: I have never heard of Windows Failover Cluster, so I cannot comment on that.